# Ubuntu Gnome to Xfce

Tags: apt, gnome, xubuntu, xfce

I am trying to install Xubuntu on a fairly fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. I want to avoid reinstalling my whole system.

While I know about `xfce4`, instead of `xubuntu-desktop`, I want to completely replace GNOME, and therefore haven't tried to install only xfce, in risk of half-installing something.

Mostly any tutorial will tell you to install it with `sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop`, but this doesn't work out-of-the-box for me. I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xubuntu-desktop : Depends: xorg but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: xubuntu-core but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

By following the instructions in these posts:
[How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa), and [I can't install XFCE ( xubuntu desktop)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/657517/i-cant-install-xfce-xubuntu-desktop/657529), I am pretty sure I don't have any broken dependencies nor unupdated/obsolete repositories.

Universe is installed and activated by default on my version of Ubuntu, which I have also confirmed.

Questions:

- What are these packages?
- Why won't they be installed?
- How do I replace GNOME with Xubuntu?
- What should I learn about desktop managers/X/window managers, and their relationship with distros?

Comment: Yeah I installed Ubuntu-MATE 18.04(.2 i think) only recently & had the same error when I tried addding `xubuntu-desktop`, but a `sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop xorg xubuntu-core` worked (going by my `history`).  Try it

Comment: Feel free to add it as an answer, @guiverc . It does answer the main problem at hand, and works. Nevertheless I would like to understand the insight of it.

Comment: Note on my prior comment:  I started with Ubuntu-MATE meaning I had 'universe' already enabled, Ubuntu does not have 'universe' repository enabled by default - so it must be enabled first.  Refer  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu if you don't understand repos

Comment: Universe was already enabled on my system, and I'm fairly sure I never touched it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed Ubuntu-MATE 18.04(*.2 i think*) only recently & had the same error when I tried adding xubuntu-desktop.  My `history`  (command history) on that box shows I then used

`sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop xorg xubuntu-core`

before moving onto different things. I was surprised by the error, but sorry i didn't explore why  (it was a x86 tablet with crap keyboard; I was going to `ssh` into the box later from a real desktop & look but forgot).

Please note: I started with Ubuntu-MATE meaning I had 'universe' already enabled, Ubuntu does not have 'universe' repository enabled by default - so it must be enabled first. Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu if you don't understand repos, but Ubuntu 18.04 LTS contains all 5 year supported code from 'main', where as flavors contain community-supported code (3 years support generally *for LTS*) from 'universe' too.

With both desktops loaded, you can select at the login screen which you want to use today. There are pro's & con's with multiple desktops (multiple programs that do the same thing, larger updates, more complex menu) but I use it very often and like it.

Comment: Can I have multiple instances of desktops running simultaneously; and if so, what benefits/cons does it bring over having multiple users?

Comment: You login to a desktop, and only a single desktop is running at the same time (using your display manager).  I have no idea if you can run multiple, but the idea to me is risky (why?) so I'd not want to explore it. Both GNOME, & XFCE allow multiple workspaces - that's what I'd use.  Under wayland would make more sense (with multiple users), but I'd not want under X or a pc.  You can run multiple X sessions (aka older minicomputer/unix with `startx`, late 80s/early 90s) but given everyone has pc's I don't see the need today.

Comment: Understandable. Any tips to completely make use of workspaces? Sharing windows on multiple workspaces, setting a workspace per monitor... (think about chats/spotify; while mainly using workspaces to swap between work and games)

Comment: I prefer using official doco if possible, so https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces.html.en  (and https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces-switch.html.en) may be helpful (esp. for GNOME).  Recent XFCE/Xubuntu starts with only one-workspace (19.04, I think 18.10 but can't recall before then) so I adding others is pretty much first thing I do maybe before changing wallpaper.  How workspaces work vary between desktops (but with XFCE & GNOME both being GTK+ they will similarities).

Comment: Another official [*community*] reference I'll provide is https://ubuntu-manual.org/  (Ubuntu Manual Project), but please note not enough people offered to help amend it to 18.04 LTS, so it's still currently written assuming Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (which used Unity). I didn't check to see if it has workspaces in it, but I'd expect it to be there (it's user-intended) even if some of the keystrokes have changed due to Unity->Gnome change.

Comment: I will take a look at them. I assume it's highly configurable.

Comment: Configuration options vary desktop to desktop.  You'll find GNOME has a different approach to others, but as I recall `gnome-tweaks` did provide some (minimal) configuration change, even if far less than other desktops.

Comment: @Andy McRae, I rejected your edit as `pluma` (MATE) `gedit` (GNOME) & `mousepad` (XFCE) do the same thing but may not be run by users simultaneously.  You may have been thinking libraries (which maybe pulled into RAM at the same time; but less of an issue if all three are GTK3 as they are in recent releases), but my wording I feel goes broader & includes end-user apps too.